A false "proof" that record setting events are dependent
Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d continuous RV.  Call $i$ record-setting if $$X_i > \max_{1 \leq j < i} X_j.$$
It is well-established on math.SE and elsewhere that the events "$X_n$ is record-setting" and "$X_{n+1}$ is record-setting" are independent.  Below is a "proof" that they are indeed dependent.  Where's the error?

Let $$M_{n} := \max\limits_{1 \leq j \leq n} X_j.$$
The event "$n$ and $n+1$ are both record-setting" occurs if and only if:

$X_n > M_{n-1}$
$X_{n+1} > M_{n-1}$
$X_{n+1} > X_n$.

By symmetry, event #1 has probability $1/n$.  Since the $X$ are i.i.d, event #2 has probability $1/n$ as well, and is independent of event #1.  Finally, given events #1 and #2, the conditional probability of event #3 is $1/2$.  Therefore the probability that both $n$ and $n+1$ are record-setters is $$P(A\cap B) = \frac 1 {2n^2} \neq \frac 1 {n(n+1)} = P(A)P(B)$$ and so the events are dependent.

You have not said what the events $A$ and $B$ are. If $A$ is $X_n>M_{n-1}$ and $B$ is $X_{n+1}>M_n$ then $P(A \cap B)=\frac1{n(n+1)}$ and they are independent.   If on the other hand  $A$ is $X_n>M_{n-1}$ and $B$ is $X_{n+1}>M_{n-1}$ and $C$ is $X_{n+1}>X_n$ then $P(A \cap B \cap C)=\frac1{n(n+1)}$ again while $P(A)P(B)P(C) =\frac1{2n^2}$ and these three events are not independent.

Events #1 and #2 are not independent of each other. Indeed, they are conditionally independent of each other given $M_{n-1}$, but not unconditionally independent of each other. Intuitively, this should make sense, since the event $\{ X_n > M_{n-1}\}$, tells us $M_{n-1}$ is more likely to be 'smaller,' which makes the event $\{X_{n+1} > M_{n-1}\}$ more likely to occur.
For a concrete example, take $X_i \sim \text{Uniform}[0,1]$ and $n = 2$. Then $M_1 = X_1$, and it is a straightforward computation (by conditioning on $X_1$) to show that $\mathbb{P}(X_2 > X_1, X_3 > X_1) = 1/3$, not $1/4$.

In fact the event ${X_n > M_{n-1}} \cap {X_{n+1} > M_{n-1}}$ is simply the event that $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are the two highest values in $(X_1,\dots, X_{n+1})$. Using a symmetry argument (to 'uniformly' select the two occurences which are highest), one can see that the probability of this event is $1/{n+1 \choose 2} = 2/(n(n+1))$.

What's fascinating is that for any given $M_{n_1}$, events #1 and #2 are (conditionally) independent; but nonetheless, events #1 and #2 are dependent.  An extreme example might be: $U, V$ each have a Bernoulli distribution with probability $S$; $S$ itself is a random variable.  For any given $S$, then $U$ and $V$ are independent, but a high value of $U$ clearly increases the probability of a high value of $V$.
